# Проблема с выдачей ролей discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, бот, discord, type-error

Я сделал в коде так, чтобы когда пользователь отправил слово "согласен", то ему выдавалась роль.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

var prefix = '!'

 client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.author === client.user) return;
    if(message.content.startsWith('согласен')) {
        var user = message.author
        user.addRole(704755953496621117)
     }
 });

client.login('секрет');
```

Но когда пользователь пишет "согласен", консоль пишет ошибку:

```
                user.addRole(704755953496621117)
                     ^

TypeError: user.addRole is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\discordbottm\bot.js:11:8)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\discordbottm\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\discordbottm\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\discordbottm\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\discordbottm\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\discordbottm\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\discordbottm\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\discordbottm\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:800:20)
```

Как исправить? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `var user = message.author` - чему равно значение `message.author` ?

Comment: @radar4ick тому кто написал это сообщение

Comment: `console.log` можно ?

Answer (score 0):

Я не могу понять, какая версия discord.js. Ты используешь способ 11 версии, но ошибка из 12 версии. [Вот тут документация по 12 версии](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/general/welcome/)

Лично я использовал так:

```
 message.member.addRole('id');
```